# Does pairwise separability of a multipartite state imply global separability?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I have two questions regarding multipartite entanglement. For simplicity, consider a tripartite pure state $|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$. My questions are :

1. How to find out if A and B are entangled with each other?
2. Does the entanglement between each pair of the parties being 0 imply that the state $|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$ is separable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on 1) To analyze the entanglement of the subsystem AB you first trace out (ignore) system C, $\rho_{AB}=\mathrm{tr}_C | \psi_{ABC} \rangle\langle \psi_{ABC} |$. Then you can use an entanglement witness or calculate an entanglement measure. [This is a review on entanglement](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.865).
on 2) A state can be entangled despite every bipartition being separable! [Here's an example](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.030403).